# Python 2.7 mock relative import

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-sphinx, python-import

Background: Wanna build a documenation for a package, which imports a C-extension relatively, eg. in an __ init__.py. Lets assume this package is called mypkg.sub. So c_ext resides in sub.

init.py of sub:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import c_ext
```

When I mock this extension I do the following in my Sphinx conf.py:

```
from mock import Mock
sys.modules['mypkg.sub.c_ext'] = Mock()
```

However I still get an import error:

> ImportError: cannot import name c_ext

The funny thing is, that the same thing works on Python3 (which has a slightly different import behaviour).

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that one can not mock c-extensions under Python-2.7, if they are relatively imported. I worked around that by using a meta_path hook to patch only these extensions.